# Adding color to a line chart based on incremental counter D3

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to set the color for a line chart based on a counter (ids3), but the colors[ids3] is not working any ideas? Thanks! Below is a snippet of the code

```
let id3 = 0;
const ids3 = function () {
    return id3++;
}  

var colors = d3.schemeCategory10;

lines.append("path")
.attr("stroke", colors[ids3])
.attr("fill","none")
.attr("stroke-width",2)
```

Comment: You should call the function: `.attr("stroke", colors[ids3()])`.

Comment: Thanks but If I do that, it doesn't really increment. For example this .attr("class", ids3) works

Comment: What do you mean by *it doesn't really increment*? It surely does: https://jsfiddle.net/5d1qas80/. Also, in your comment (`.attr("class", ids3)`) you are actually calling the function (by the way, you should not set class names starting with numbers).

Comment: Thanks Gerardo, what I mean is that when I inspect the path elements they all have the first color only

Comment: At this point I suggest you post a [MCVE].